# my jmeter script is running inspite of the application server being shut down

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I created a jmeter script for an MSTR application. The server on which this application is hosted was shut down by the Development team but my script is still running successfully.

Why is the script not giving errors??

Comment: The server may have a "under maitainece" page that is returning an OK status (200).

Answer (score 2):

In case of [HTTP Requests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) JMeter automatically treats all [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) which are less than 400 as successful.

You can consider adding i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to ensure that the test is doing what it needs to do and, expected information is present at the page, not expected information is not present, etc. You can also set maximum response time via [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion), check response for being HTML/XHTML/XML-compliant via [HTML Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Assertion), etc.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for comprehensive information on conditionally failing JMeter samplers using assertions

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an impression that the script is running successfully based on the response code you are receiving. For correctness of the tests, it is advised that you add response assertions to your scripts and add certain text as a pattern which is expected as result of successful response for respective request.

In this case you also need to make sure that you don't add response assertion for each and every request as it can make the JMeter script heavy to execute and JMeter may run out of memory if appropriate memory is not allocated.

Add a response assertion and re-run the test and make practice to use it to validate the correctness of your script.